# Get list index on form submission in Django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a form where a user can submit an arbitrary number of inputs, which I have setup using jquery.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'review:submit_review' %}">
  <ol id="bibliography">
    <li><input type="url" name="references"></li>
  </ol>
  <button name="add-reference">+</button>
  <button name="remove-reference">-</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

$("button[name='add-reference']").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#bibliography").append('<li><input type="url" name="references">');
})
$("button[name='remove-reference']").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#bibliography input[name='references']").last().parent().remove()
})
```

I would like to have it, so that when the form is submitted, I know the index number of the input field. i.e. For a given `reference` what was its list number. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: so, all your dynamic form fields are with the same name `references`? I think this is not a good practise. Why not change the name to `references-0`, 'references-1', etc, .... then you can catch the index from the backend.

Comment: @Enix I thought about that.  However, assigning `references` to all of them returned a dictionary with key `references` and a value of a list of the submitted references (`{'references':[url1, url2, url3...]}`) - this was convent for parsing the data. It might not be good practice though...